# Evitar vistas dinámicas en cache con Service Worker

Tags: php, javascript, cache, service-workers

Estos implementando un Service Worker en una Tienda en línea, hasta ahora todo bien, implemente la estrategia de Cache Network Fallback y parece funcionar bien, solo tengo un problema, las vistas dinámicas también se guardan en el cache, es decir, guarda el archivo, carrito.php tal cual pero cuando agrego un producto al carrito sigue mostrando la primera vista, es decir sin el producto, asumo que es por el tema del cache, el cache lo estoy guardando en un cache dinámico, pero no estoy seguro como evitar que las vistas .php se guarden o se refresquen al haber contenido diferente.

El navegador convierte ese .php en una vista html, por lo que no guarda ese archivo .php tal cual, pero si el codigo de la vista html y la sigue mostrando aunque haya cambiado.

Este es el código del Service Worker:

```
importScripts( 'assets/js/sw-utils.js' );

const STATIC_CACHE = 'static-v1';
const DYNAMIC_CACHE = 'dynamic-v1';
const INMUTABLE_CACHE = 'inmutable-v1';

const APP_SHELL = [
    // Mis librerias
    '/',
    'assets/style.css',
];

const APP_SHELL_INMUTABLE = [
    'assets/boostrap.min.css',
];

self.addEventListener( 'install', e => {
    const cacheStatic = caches.open( STATIC_CACHE ).then(cache => cache.addAll( APP_SHELL ));
    const cacheInmutable = caches.open( INMUTABLE_CACHE ).then(cache => cache.addAll( APP_SHELL_INMUTABLE ));
    e.waitUntil( Promise.all([ cacheStatic, cacheInmutable ]) );
});

self.addEventListener( 'activate', e => {
    const respuesta = caches.keys().then( keys => {
        keys.forEach( key => {
            if ( key !== STATIC_CACHE && key.includes( 'static') ) {
                return caches.delete(key);
            }
        });
    });
    e.waitUntil( respuesta );
});

self.addEventListener( 'fetch', e => {
    const respuesta = caches.match( e.request ).then( res => {
        if ( res ) {
            return res;
        } else {
            return fetch( e.request ).then( newRes => {
                return actualizaCacheDinamico( DYNAMIC_CACHE, e.request, newRes );
            });
        }
    });
    e.respondWith( respuesta );
});
```

Y este del archivo que crea el cache dinámico (Los archivos que se actualizaran cada cierto tiempo como las imágenes de productos):

```
function actualizaCacheDinamico( dynamicCache, req, res ) {
    if ( res.ok ) {
        return caches.open( dynamicCache ).then( cache => {
            cache.put( req, res.clone() );
            return res.clone();
        });
    } else {
        return res;
    }
}
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.